# Please explain why these two builtin functions behave different when passed in keyword arguments

Tags: python

Consider these different behaviour::

```
>> def minus(a, b):
>>    return a - b

>> minus(**dict(b=2, a=1))
-1

>> int(**dict(base=2, x='100'))
4

>> import operator
>> operator.sub.__doc__
'sub(a, b) -- Same as a - b.'
>> operator.sub(**dict(b=2, a=1))
TypeError: sub() takes no keyword arguments
```

Why does `operator.sub` behave differently from `int(x, [base])` ?

Comment: It would be nice if people could also answer why this function choses not to use keyword arguments, I would like to know this as well :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an implementation detail. The [Python C API to retrieve arguments](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html#PyArg_UnpackTuple) separates between positional and keyword arguments. Positional arguments do not even have a name internally.

The code used to retrieve the arguments of the `operator.add` functions (and similar ones like `sub`) is this:

```c
PyArg_UnpackTuple(a,#OP,2,2,&a1,&a2)
```

As you can see, it does not contain any argument name. The whole code related to `operator.add` is:

```c
#define spam2(OP,AOP) static PyObject *OP(PyObject *s, PyObject *a) { \
  PyObject *a1, *a2; \
  if(! PyArg_UnpackTuple(a,#OP,2,2,&a1,&a2)) return NULL; \
  return AOP(a1,a2); }

spam2(op_add           , PyNumber_Add)
```

```c
#define spam2(OP,ALTOP,DOC) {#OP, op_##OP, METH_VARARGS, PyDoc_STR(DOC)}, \
                           {#ALTOP, op_##OP, METH_VARARGS, PyDoc_STR(DOC)},
spam2(add,__add__, "add(a, b) -- Same as a + b.")
```

As you can see, the only place where `a` and `b` are used is in the docstring. The method definition also does not use the `METH_KEYWORDS` flag which would be necessary for the method to accept keyword arguments.

Generally spoken, you can safely assume that a python-based function where you know an argument name will **always** accept keyword arguments (of course someone could do nasty stuff with `*args` unpacking but creating a function doc where the arguments look normal) while C functions may or may not accept keyword arguments. Chances are good that functions with more than a few arguments or optional arguments accept keyword arguments for the later/optional ones. But you pretty much have to test it.

You can find a discussion about supporting keyword arguments everywhere on the [python-ideas mailinglist](http://groups.google.com/group/python-ideas/browse_thread/thread/9bf7674861d656d9?pli=1). There is also a statement from *Guido van Rossum* (the [Benevolent Dictator For Life](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BDFL) aka the creator of Python) on it:

> Hm. I think for many (most?) 1-arg and selected 2-arg functions (and
>   rarely 3+-arg functions) this would reduce readability, as the example
>   of ord(char=x) showed.
>
> I would actually like to see a syntactic feature to state that an
>   argument *cannot* be given as a keyword argument (just as we already
>   added syntax to state that it *must* be a keyword).
>
> One area where I think adding keyword args is outright wrong: Methods
>   of built-in types or ABCs and that are overridable. E.g. consider the
>   pop() method on dict. Since the argument name is currently
>   undocumented, if someone subclasses dict and overrides this method, or
>   if they create another mutable mapping class that tries to emulate
>   dict using duck typing, it doesn't matter what the argument name is --
>   all the callers (expecting a dict, a dict subclass, or a dict-like
>   duck) will be using positional arguments in the call. But if we were
>   to document the argument names for pop(), and users started to use
>   these, then most dict sublcasses and ducks would suddenly be broken
>   (except if by luck they happened to pick the same name).

Comment: Beyond the stylistic choice, I should point out that accepting keyword arguments at all adds overhead to the function call, and if the user actually passes arguments by keyword to a built-in, the overhead goes up significantly. Microbenchmarks in Python 3.5 for `int("0", 2)` vs. `int("0", base=2)` on my machine show the latter takes ~2.5x as long to run; more time is spent argument parsing than on actual work. Worse is functions taking a single argument, which have a fast path that avoids argument wrapping, but moving to keywords means arguments must be wrapped in a `tuple` and/or `dict`.

Answer (score 4):

`operator` is a C module, which [defines functions differently](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#PyMethodDef). Unless the function declaration in the module initialization includes `METH_KEYWORDS`, the function will not accept keyword arguments under any conditions and you get the error given in the question.

Answer (score 3):

`minus(**dict(b=2, a=1))` expands to `minus(b=2, a=1)`. This works because your definition has argument names `a` and `b`.

`operator.sub(**dict(b=2, a=1))` expands to `operator.sub(b=2, a=1)`. This doesn't work because sub does not accept keyword arguments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is asking why it does not accept keyword arguments and you have not answered that.

Comment: Are you saying that operator.sub does not have its arguments named like `minus` ?

Comment: @BonAmi: Exactly. `operator.sub`'s arguments are nameless

Comment: @Eric So `int` is not implement in C ? How do I check ?

Comment: @BonAmi: Not sure you can. `inspect.getargspec` was my first guess, but that errors on C functions. Pretty sure `int` is implemented in C, but with explicitly named arguments.